# XCode 4.2 gives error on installation

Tags: macos, xcode4

ALL,
I have a Mac with Snow Leopard.
In order to compile and test my program I installed XCode from the original Snow Leopard installation CD. The version was 3.2.
However, my client has Snow Leopard with XCode 4.2 and the program didn't compile, so I decided to remove old XCode and install 4.2.

I downloaded XCode 4.2 and then issued following:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
rm -rf /Develop
```

Then I tried to install XCode 4.2, but got an error:

An unknown installation error occured.
The installer encountered error that caused an installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/410573/cant-install-xcode-on-os-x-snow-leopard) posting, which fixed it for me as well.
XCode installed without issues.